# Finding eigenvectors with given set of eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have a matrix whose eigenvalues I was trying calculate. Mathematica miserably failed in calculating the eigenvalues. So, I calculated them manually. But can I use it to find eigenvalues, atleast.

```
Hg = ( {
    {0, k1, k2},
    {k1, 0, k3},
    {k2, k3, 0}} );
```

But let us say, I have `l1`, `l2` and `l3` as my eigenvalues. Can I find the eigenvectors? Can I get the eigennvalues for this symbolic matrix?

Comment: "miserably failed"? Eigensystem[{{0, k1, k2}, {k1, 0, k3}, {k2, k3, 0}}] // ToRadicals

Comment: Try to make it answer. Thanks @KraZug

Comment: I suspect that the question should be closed actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Eigensystem` or `Eigenvalues` will give answers in terms of Root expressions for non-numerical values, you can force them to give radicals (when they are degree <5) with `ToRadicals`.

`Eigensystem[{{0, k1, k2}, {k1, 0, k3}, {k2, k3, 0}}] // ToRadicals`